# Memory Size Allocation on GPU - opengl texture loading question

Tags: java, opengl, gpu, javax.imageio, lwjgl

I'm loading pixels from an image which is 32 w by 32 height.  The format I'm loading them in is ARGB via java.  When I bind this to the video card, I can expect that the video card might use somewhere around 32*32*4 bytes, or 4K.

Similarly, 1024 w, 1024 h would be 1024*1024*4 = 4MB.

Is my understanding correct?  Now I understand where all the memory goes!

Comment: I'm confused. Did you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact amount of memory used is not something that you will be able to compute because each implementation has its own (internal) constraints on textures. Amongst them:

- alignment requirement for the base pointer(s)
- constraints on the width and height
- specific constraints on mip-maps (there are many potential ones here).

So in short, you can guestimate a lower-bound on memory usage, but you'd better add some room for additional stuff that each GL implementation might use.

(As a side note, mip-mapping is something you definitely should take into account. It adds at least 1/3 of the base layer if in use).

Comment: thanks bahbar, those are excellent points.  @marcelo, sorta yeah. i just wanted to make sure i thought i knew what was going on.